# php mail function within function - how secure is this?

Tags: php

I've been reading into php mail injection and possible security risks. I've decided to control most of this via a function and simply pass in the from email and contact message.

just wondered how secure this was and does it prevent any sort of injection?

```
//contact form
function sendContactForm($contactEmail, $contactMessage) {

    $to = "mysite@mysite.com";
    $from = "mysite@mysite.com";

    $replyTo = filter_var($contactEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    $subject = "Contact Form Email";
    $message = $contactMessage;

    $headers  = "From: " . $from . "\r\n"; 
    $headers  = "Reply-To:" . $replyTo . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

    $success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
```

Comment: It looks like you want `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL`

Comment: i would suggest using phpmailer (http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/). i think it already solves alot of security issues

Answer (score 1):

It's not really secure: an user could easily inject some code in `$contactMessage`.

My suggestion is to use [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), that converts characters in entities (where possible).

You can also use [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), which returns a string without HTML tags.

Comment: htmlspecialchars() would suffice in nearly all cases of html escaping.